# One to One relationship in coredata using swift

Tags: swift, core-data, nsset

I'm new with swift and trying to maintain one to one relationship with my receipt-invoice coredata.

I'm unable to set the relation using NSSet. Below is my code:

```
func addReceipt(receipt: NSMutableDictionary){

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let entityReceipt = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Receipt", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    let newReceipt = NSManagedObject(entity: entityReceipt!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    if let invoice = addInvoic(receipt){
        newReceipt.setValue(NSSet(object: invoice), forKey: "invoice")
    }
}

func addInvoic(receipt: NSMutableDictionary) -> NSManagedObject!{

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let entityInvoice = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Invoice", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let newInvoice = NSManagedObject(entity: entityInvoice!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    newInvoice.setValue(receipt.valueForKey("companyName"), forKey: "companyName")
    newInvoice.setValue(receipt.valueForKey("address"), forKey: "address")
    newInvoice.setValue(receipt.valueForKey("merchant"), forKey: "merchant")


    var returnObj: NSManagedObject!
    if (saveObject()){
        returnObj = newInvoice
    }
    return returnObj
}
```

This method successfully save the invoice and returns the save NSManagedObject. But when I tries to set that object it gives me following error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSetI managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16ee0960'
*** First throw call stack:(0x24ad35a7 0x327f1c77 0x24ad8a6d 0x24ad6949 0x24a07b68 0x247fadf1 0x247fa09d 0x24819077 0x2481de37 0x90360 0x9d3b0 0x871dc 0x85130 0x8a48c 0x934a4 0x84c2c 0x84db4 0x28008707 0x280086a9 0x27ff343d 0x280080d9 0x28007db3 0x280016c1 0x27fd7fbd 0x2824bbb5 0x27fd6a07 0x24a9a237 0x24a9964b 0x24a97cc9 0x249e4b51 0x249e4963 0x2bf4a1a9 0x28036c91 0x5a044 0x32d9aaaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

For objective-C, I was implementing it as

```
[NSSet setWithObject:invoice]
```

I don't know where I am making mistake. Please help. Any help will the appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show more of the code.

Comment: If it is a one-to-one relationship, the object for key "invoice" should be a single invoice object rather than an NSSet.

Comment: @Bluehound Thank  you. I had replaced it  with            newReceipt.setValue(invoice, forKey: "invoice") and it's solved